# How to configure Kotlin version in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have configured the Kotlin version in project's build.gradle. But in Other Settings->Kotlin Compiler , it shows an older version.
How to fix that?

[image: project's build.gradle]

[image: Android Studio's Settings]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is not showing you outdated version. Let's say your plugin version is '1.1.3', so your compiler version is '1.1' not '1.1.3'. Now, if you will update your kotlin by going in

> Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Updates

to early access version '1.2' as shown in screenshot below, you will be able to see '1.2' in you 'Kotlin compiler' settings.

[image]

Comment: To select a specific Kotlin version for a project go to:
 Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project

Comment: @YordanBoev I've tried your suggestion but it does not seem to work. It keeps setting the version to 1.9.0-Beta and I do not know how to change that. Even if I start a new project it somehow defaults to Kotlin 1.9.0-Beta now and I can select the 1.8.21 version but after I press OK nothing really happens. If I open the settings it just says 1.9.0-Beta again.

Answer (score 21):

In the newer versions of the Android Studio project,

Go to **build.gradle(Project)**

[image: Gradle File]

change version of that compiler will ask you to update.

Comment: Warning: Be careful with that. On some occasions, Android Studio overwrites the id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version line with whatever it thinks is right(mostly 1.6.21 in my case)

Comment: @r-hold, how do you override that?

Comment: I just edited the file. Put obviously you are not supposed to do that

Comment: I LOVE YOU! Oh my god I searched for this stupidy thing for so much time and no one on the internet seems to know how to point to such a SIMPLE thing. Think you so much for being right to the point.

Comment: Ha ha.. Welcome, I have been to that pain and then i decided to add updated answer to SO.

Answer (score 4):

In your Android studio,
 Go to Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Updates.

For more details you can check 
   https://segunfamisa.com/posts/setting-up-android-studio-for-kotlin-development

Answer (score 0):

For React Native, the below solution works. Apply this fix to your top level `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    // ...
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
+       exclusiveContent {
+           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
+           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
+           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
+           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
+           filter {
+               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
+           }
+           forRepository {
+               maven {
+                   // NOTE: if you are in a monorepo, you may have "$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
+                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
+               }
+           }
+       }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Open you project gradle and add this line

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3-2"
```

After configuration project Gradle you need to add app Gradle. add kotlin plugin after android plugin like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

And the Last step add dependencies

```
   compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3-2"
```

And Click SYNC Project.